# API calls not not redirected to the required target despite adding a proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, proxy, axios, create-react-app

Despite adding a proxy, the API calls are not redirected to the required target url.

I have created a chatbot app using create-react-app. I want to redirect all API calls made from `http://localhost:3000/` to `http://localhost:5000/` and to get this done I have configured the proxy as per the instructions in https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually

When compiling the code, it seems that the proxy has be added but on running the application in the browser, the api calls have not been redirected to `http://localhost:5000`

Proxy setup code:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));
}
```

API calls:

```
const chatbot = require('../reactbot-backend/chatbot')

module.exports = app => {

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    res.send({'hello': 'johnny'});

});

app.post('/api/df_text_query', async (req, res) => {
    let responses = await chatbot.textQuery(req.body.text, req.body.parameters);
    res.send(responses[0].queryResult);
});

app.post('/api/df_event_query', async (req, res) => {
    let responses = await chatbot.eventQuery(req.body.event, req.body.parameters);
    res.send(responses[0].queryResult);
});
};
```

On compiling the code i get the following:

```
[0] [HPM] Proxy created: /api/*  ->  http://localhost:5000/
[0] Starting the development server...
[0]
[0] Compiled successfully!
```

This is the error obtained on API calls:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/df_event_query:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

createError.js:17 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

`http://localhost:3000/api/df_event_query` suggests that the api calls have not been redirected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `changeOrigin:true` solved this issue

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' , changeOrigin: true}));
}
```